# Does the Film Drive Have a Cameo from the star of Maniac Cop

Tags: character, casting, drive

The Film Drive has the Below image:

[image]

Is this an uncredited Cameo from Laurene Landon, the star of the Maniac cop films? It looks like her, and Refn has gone on record as saying he is a fan of those films, and was at one point attached to produce or possibly direct the remake. Also I know that Jay Bauman of RedLetterMedia had a very similar question, but I could not find an answer.

Comment: If that's not her, that's some amazing lookalike. She's [credited for the role](http://simple-movie.com/actor/laurene-landon_87612/) on an online film archive, but I don't know if that means much.

Comment: It would be unlikely that her agents wouldn't add "Drive" to the IMDb page for her, considering it would greatly help her career if it was indeed her. So I'd say it's a lookalike. You can try to ask NWR on his Twitter: https://twitter.com/nicolaswr

Answer (score 4):

It's her. Laurene Landon herself [confirmed it](https://twitter.com/LaureneLandon/status/701471127684558848) on Twitter. According to her, the part was cut short due to time constraints.